# Kafka credentials and consumer parameters for c++ client

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am trying to consume kafka msg using c++.
I have installed librdkafka and trying the example https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.cpp

Now my concern is how to pass **username, password and truststore** to kafka consumer?

Comment: Have you looked at the main Readme for the available properties around ssl or sasl configs? Truststore is only in Java. You need to convert to a certificate

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which authentication mechanism that the broker is configured with you will need to configure the client with the following configuration properties:

- `security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT` or `SASL_SSL`, depending on if SSL is used.
- `sasl.mechanism=PLAIN` or any of the other mechanisms, see [CONFIGURATION.md](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md)
- `sasl.username=...` and `sasl.password=..` for PLAIN and SCRAM-.. mechanisms.
- `sasl.kerberos.service.name=..` for GSSAPI/Kerberos.

See [CONFIGURATION.md](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) for all available configuration properties, SASL mechanisms, etc.

Comment: Hi Edenhill, Thanks for the response. I am trying to understand your example provided at https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_complex_consumer_example.cpp I can see brokers, groupid values taken as cmd arguments. I am bit confused, how to pass configuration.properties. to This C++ program. Do the temporary configuration object automatically picks up the properties?

Comment: `conf->set("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT", errstr);`